# Why my constructor function raise segmentation fault when it exits?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm pretty new to C++, and finding difficulty digging into memory management or things alike. Now I am trying to write some rudimentary parser but has the constructor function exits with a segmentation fault and cannot find out why.

Somewhere on the web has informed me that this is caused by I myself somehow corrupted the stack, but I'm to new to realize the origin of the problem.

```
class Parser {
public:
    int *res, len = 0;
    string src;

// this len is the number of seps
Parser(const string &s, char t) : src(s) {
    int tmp = -1, flag = TRUE, tmps[MAX];
    while (flag) {
        tmp = s.find(t, tmp + 1);
        if (tmp == -1) {
            flag = FALSE;
        } else {
            tmps[len++] = tmp;  // len is now really the length
        }
    }
    res = (int *) malloc(len * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        *(res + i) = tmps[i];
    }
}

~Parser() {
    free(res);
    }
};
```

When run directly, report "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"; and when in debugging mode, raise "SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)" at "mov %rax,(%rcx)", the instruction.

Comment: please provide a use case

Comment: `int *res`;`  - warning - because how do you handle that?

Comment: ... and:
`res = (int *) malloc(len * sizeof(int))`

No, it's not C++.

Comment: What is `MAX` defined as? What does `s` actually contain, and what is `t` set to? Did you validate to make sure your loop is not going out of bounds of the `tmps[]` array? Please provide a [mcve] showing how you are calling the constructor. Also, you are not checking if `malloc()` fails. Use `new[]` instead of `malloc()`. But why are you using both a fixed array and a dynamic array to collect the indexes, instead of just using a `std::vector` and let it grow itself as needed?

Comment: Also, your class violates the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).  Switching to `std::vector` would fix that.

Comment: and the result of "function raise segmentation fault when it exits" is ... not defined.

Comment: Compile it with the **-g** option, run it with **gdb** and when you get the segfault use the command **bt** to see where it originated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank all your help, now I have fix my code up, and here I offer a complete solution for my little parser, with usages.

```
#define MAX 99
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define INFEASIBLE -1
#define OVERFLOW -2

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Parser {
public:
vector<int> res;
int len;
string src;

Parser(string s, char t) : src(move(s)) {
    // churn a string and a seperator into a vector of ints
    int sep, next_sep, tmp;
    for (sep = -1, next_sep = 0; next_sep != -1; sep = next_sep) {
        next_sep = src.find(t, sep + 1);
        if (next_sep == -1) {
            res.push_back(stoi(src.substr(sep+1)));
        } else if (sep == -1) {
            res.push_back(stoi(src.substr(0, next_sep)));
        } else {
            res.push_back(stoi(src.substr(sep+1, next_sep - sep - 1)));
        }
    }
    len = res.size();
}
};


class TwoTierParser {
public:
vector<Parser> res;
int len;
string src;

TwoTierParser(string s, char x, char y) : src(move(s)) {
    // churn a string and two seperators into a vector of Parsers
    int sep, next_sep;
    for (sep = -1, next_sep = 0; next_sep != -1; sep = next_sep) {
        next_sep = src.find(x, sep + 1);
        if (next_sep == -1) {
            res.emplace_back(Parser(src.substr(sep+1), y));
        } else if (sep == -1) {
            res.emplace_back(Parser(src.substr(0, next_sep), y));
        } else {
            res.emplace_back(Parser(src.substr(sep+1, next_sep - sep - 1), y));
        }
    }
    len = res.size();
}
};


int main() {
char comma = ',', semicolon = ';';
string a;
//    cin >> a;
a = "1,2,3,4,5;6,7,8,9,10;11,12,13,14,15";
TwoTierParser parse(a, semicolon, comma);


int row = parse.len;
int col = parse.res[0].len;
int matrix[row][col];

for(int i=0; i<row; ++i){
    for(int j=0; j<col; ++j){
        matrix[i][j]=parse.res[i].res[j];
    }
}

for (int k = 0; k < row; ++k) {
    for (int i = 0; i < col; ++i) {
        cout<<matrix[k][i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}
return 0;
}
```